# Multistatement processing in Oracle via Perl DBI

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi

Is there a way I can do something like this using Oracle / DBI / Perl.

```
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect( oracle_stuff );
my $sql = <<EOF;
select current_timestamp(3) from dual;
select current_timestamp(3) from dual;
EOF
my $sth  = $dbh->prepare($sql);
print $sth->execute();
```

Obviously I want to process something a lot larger than just 2 x current_datetimes , but this is my trivial example. I keep getting the error : SQL command not properly ended :-(

Comment: don't think it is possible. but why do you need it? can't it be done as separate statements?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5604057

Comment: I am porting a large amount of code from sybase -> oracle... I really would like to be able to keep most of the SQL as close as possible to the original. My example is a bit misleading ... it is not just executing the same command a few times, but one command might be an insert, the next a delete etc etc ...

Answer (score 0):

the prepare statement is waiting for a '?' like suggest the doc of the DBI package here http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm

for example :

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('select current_timestamp(?) from dual')
$sth->execute(3);
$sth->execute(4);
$sth->execute(5);
```

etc...

Comment: Yes... but I don't want to run the same code over and over again - the commands are completely different - ie one insert, one delete, another insert etc etc.

Comment: if the statements are unrelated, then there's no reason to group them together as a whole; if the are related, then they're (like) a single transaction; set autocommit to false and commit after the last statement (and rollback if one fails).

Comment: @richardgreen in that case it looks like that the daxim 's link is fine [https://metacpan.org/module/SQL::SplitStatement](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL::SplitStatement)