# Use Perl DBI to execute an entire SQL file as in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: perl, oracle, sqlplus, dbi

I need to execute an SQL file against an Oracle database using the Perl DBI. With a quick search I found some solutions executing the SQL file by line by line, but I want to load the SQL in its entirety file as in SQL Developer.

In SQL Dveloper or SQL*Plus command line I can execute;

```
@/path/to/file.sql;
```

If I execute this statement in Perl as below

```
my $query = "@/path/to/file.sql";
my $sth  = $dbh->prepare($query)
        or die "Couldn't prepare query: ". $dbh->errstr;    
$sth->execute();
```

I get the error: `ORA-00900: Invalid statement`

Comment: You can't execute more than one SQL statement at a time using DBI. Why don't you want to do it line by line? And why don't you use SQL*Plus if it does what you want?

Comment: Are you aware that SQL Developer and SQL*Plus do this one statement at a time too? There isn't a way of doing a complete script all at once whatever tool you use

Comment: @Borodin: The question probably means whether it is possible to bulk load a file into a db using DBI.

Comment: You can have a [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601007/how-do-i-use-perl-and-regular-expressions-to-convert-a-sql-document-to-coldfusio/5604057#5604057) which permits to handle each line one by one.

Comment: I'm not sure if [DBI::Shell](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI%3A%3AShell) would help or not.  It has a 'load' command to read the content of a file ready to execute it, but I don't know if it splits the contents of that file into separate executable statements that it executes separately.

Answer (score 1):

sqlplus, while processing the file, executes a SQL statement when it reads a semicolon (';') at the end of a line, or a forward slash ('/') on a line. If you want to process it with perl and DBI, you'll have to split up the statements in the same way and execute them one at a time, stripping the '/' and ';' before you execute. And keep in mind that 'execute some_stored_procedure()' is a sqlplus statement, not a SQL statement, and you will have to expand it before executing in DBI (see DBD::Oracle).

Also, if you do this, you won't need prepare() and execute(), you just need do().

Answer (score -3):

The question probably means whether it is possible to bulk load a file into a db using DBI.

Is it possible? I try to do the following:

```
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI-> connect('dbi:ODBC:test','test','test');
my $sql="@\test.sql";
$dbh->do($sql);
```

I have test.sql in my current directory with a simple sql statement.

I need this for a new odbc test driver and fit it into some test framework. Thx.

Comment: A definite answer should be provided here and not a new question.